# Postgresql Serialize

Tags: postgresql, serialization

Is it possible to search a field that was serialized in php and stored like that in postgresql ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regexp match, but it won't be fast:

```
select * from table where field ~* 'sometext';
```